# How user select from the chart area and export the selected data to .csv file?

Tags: c#, csv, charts

I want to select area of the Graph and export those area's data to .csv file in C#.As an example chart is Age vs. Name,then user select area of this chart and those data export to .csv file under Age and Name.

I can not imagine how I do that.I searched from internet but I could not find any helping code for that.

Comment: So you want let the user select data points from a chart and export the values?

Comment: Hi, please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Your question is too broad and you haven't mentioned what framework are you working with.

Comment: For multiple selections see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181926/selecting-multiple-sections-on-a-chart-in-c-sharp/39248410?s=3|0.7330#39248410) ! - Th eCSV export should be trivial..

Comment: @TaW,yes i want to select data points and get that selected area data to .csv file.please give me any help for that.

Comment: Well, the linked answer should do the job of selecting all the points you want. If you have special question do ask.

Comment: @TaW please tell me where is the linked answer that you told previous.thank you

Comment: Right at the top of this page:: _Selecting specific values on a Chart_

Comment: @TaW I tried that code but ,  if (rect.Contains(new Point(x,y))) selectedPoints.Add(dp);there is occur null exception(An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GraphExcel.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).why is that.please explain sir.

Comment: Did you initialize `selectedPoints`? It should be declared at class level.. I intialize it in the MouseDown.

Comment: @TaW,Yes I did sir..

Comment: Then do use the debugger to test which variable in null! I can't do that for you..!

Comment: I am trying now